# Except only + clause?

Tags: grammaticality

> "...what things do they provide us? For instance, a donkey looks like a horse, **except only it is smaller than a horse**."

As you can see, the bold part confuses me. As far as I know, *except* is used as conjunction with a clause, such as:

> "I would like to bail him out, except I don’t have any money."

I don't know whether the bold part in the sentence I posted above is grammatically correct. Please help me!

Comment: Can you specify the source where you came across this?

Comment: Use either "except" or "only". The rest should be rewritten.

Comment: @Mamta D: It's from a book of XACT BOOK (Indian publisher).

Comment: "except that it is" "except it is" "excepting only that it is"  "only it is" all work better.

Comment: That just looks very badly written to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying it's incorrect but it doesn't feel natural. I would use [except that](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/except-that):

> used to give a reason why something is not possible or true

[Cambridge Online Dictionary]

> A donkey looks like a horse, **except that** it is smaller than a horse.

or simply

> A donkey looks like a horse, only smaller.

Answer (score 0):

This is archaic construction, where *except* may be interpreted to mean: *with the exception (that)*. What is your source? I would avoid this type of use in modern writing, but you may still see it in older texts.

The phrase *except only* is decreasing in popularity; see [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=except%20only&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cexcept%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bexcept%20only%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BExcept%20only%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: It's from a book of XACT BOOK (Indian publisher).

Answer (score 0):

I searched through   Corpus of Contemporary American English and found only 10 sentences. therefore, I can say it is a very rare usage.

You can use "except that", which is more common.

For instance, a donkey looks like a horse, **except that** it is smaller than a horse."

Comment: "Except that" was suggested by 0xFEE1DEAD. Can you include how many sentences you found using "except that" and show us how rare "except only" is?